# How do the Raspbian and OSMC repositories differ?

Tags: raspbian, apt, osmc

My stock Raspbian system has `libswscale2` available in the repositories, but OSMC does not. How do the repositories differ?

In Raspbian:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/raspbian/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

In OSMC:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://apt.osmc.tv jessie main
```

I actually manually added `rpi` to the OSMC file, as it was missing earlier, but this did not help.